# How to display dropdown list of sublime-snippets in html files

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I have created a libary with about 80 sublime-snippet's.
They work great on my machine which is the machine I created them on. I then passed my folder out to two of my fellow employees so that they could use the new library of snippets I created. The only issue is the snippets won't work on their machines. They are installing it in /Sublime Text 3/Packages/MySnippetFolder. These snippets are meant to be used in .html files. However they are only showing up in .py files for my coworkers. Scope is commented out in the sublime-snippet files so shouldn't they appear in .html files as well? Any advice is appreciated thank you  very much for your time in advance.

Edit: Ok So the snippets are working as intended I believe. The thing I am confused about now is when I use it in a python file a dropdown list appears that contains my snippets. When I try this in my html files there is no drop list containing my snippets. Is there a way to have to drop down list appear in my html files as well like it does for the bootstrap 3/4 snippets package?

Here is an example of the code for one of my snippets.

```
    <snippet>
      <content><![CDATA[
    <div class="form-group v-spacing-extra-large">
        <p>Minimum: <strong>1</strong> | Maximum: <strong>10</strong> | Multiple <small>(Step)</small>: <strong>1</strong>
        </p>
        <div class="input-stepper-group">
            <a aria-label="Decrease Quantity by 1" tabindex="0" data-stepper-role="decrease" data-stepper-target="#demo-stepper-three" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary js-stepper-control disabled"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-minus"></i></a>
            <input aria-describedby="product-qty-three-stepper-aria-describedby" aria-label="quantity" data-toggle="stepper" data-round="up" id="demo-stepper-three" class="form-control stepper" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" data-min="1" data-max="10" data-step="1" value="1">
            <a aria-label="Increase Quantity by 1" tabindex="0" data-stepper-role="increase" data-stepper-target="#demo-stepper-three" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary js-stepper-control"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <span id="product-qty-three-stepper-aria-describedby" class="ada screen-reader-only">Initial Quantity is set to 1. Max Quantity is set to 10 and the step multiple is set to 1.</span>
    </div>
    ]]></content>
      <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
      <tabTrigger>ff-stepper-min1-max10-stepby1</tabTrigger> 
      <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
      <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
    </snippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the dropdown list appear in your html files unless you have another package installed to enable this just type < before your snippet code. So if you have a my-snippet.sublime-snippet , then to use that you would type "<"my-snippet wihtout the "'s and you would see the drop down once you began typing.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> anywhere in the code to get the snippets dropdown.